# Help with this part of proof for d'Alembert convergence test

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, proof-explanation

If $\lim_{n \to \infty}\left\lvert\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right\rvert=\alpha>1$ then the series $S = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ diverges.

*Proof.*

For $\alpha>1$ there is $N \in \mathbb{N}$ so that $\left\lvert\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right\rvert>1 \iff |a_{n+1}|>|a_n|$. Therefore it is not true $a_n \rightarrow 0 \text{ as } n \rightarrow \infty$, and by that the series S diverges.

*End of proof.*

---

**My question:**

Why does from $|a_{n+1}|>|a_n|$ follow $\lim_{n \to \infty}a_n \neq 0$? Are we able to conclude this only because the sequence is increasing ? And if yes why is it enough in this case ? Why isn't it possible, let's say, that $a_1=-10$, $ a_k=-0,0001$, $ a_n \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ ? Because $|a_{n+1}|>|a_n|$ ?

Sorry if I am asking silly questions, I am still figuring all this out.

Thanks

Comment: Is $|-0,0001| > |-10|$?

Comment: @UmbertoP. No it is not

Answer (score 1):

Let's proof that $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n}\neq0$ by showing that there exists such $\varepsilon$ that for each $n_{0}$ we can find $n>n_{0}$ for which $|a_{n}|>\varepsilon$. Remember: $a_{n}\to0\iff |a_{n}|\to0$. Let's choose $\varepsilon=|a_{0}|$. $|a_{n}|$ is strictly increasing, therefore for every $n_{0}>1$ we can find $n>n_{0}$ (for example, $n=n_{0}+1$) that suffices $|a_{n}|>|a_{0}|$. This is the contradiction of the limit definition, meaning $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n}\neq 0$.

Answer (score 0):

It is assumed here that $a_n\neq 0$ atleast for large $n$ so that $\frac {a_{n+1}} {a_n}$ makes sense. Suppose $a_{n_0} \neq 0$.  Now verify by induction that $|a_n| >|a_{n_0}|$ for all $n >n_0$. This implies that $a_n$ does not tend to $0$.